# Connecting to Laravel echo presence channel problem

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I have a problem with connecting to presence channel, It is authenticated successfully and it is fired to the client but the event details are missed.
The problem message is: **Unable to join channel. Member data for presence channel missing**

Laravel console:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.2

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!


- OWCJjy4o64iDbqMOAAAA joined channel: public_channel
- Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost/app/public/index.php/api/v1
- Sending auth request to: http://localhost/app/public/index.php/api/v1/broadcasting/auth


- Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost/app/public/index.php/api/v1
- Sending auth request to: http://localhost/app/public/index.php/api/v1/broadcasting/auth

- OWCJjy4o64iDbqMOAAAA authenticated for: private-private-channel
- OWCJjy4o64iDbqMOAAAA joined channel: private-private-channel
- OWCJjy4o64iDbqMOAAAA authenticated for: presence-presence-channel.1
******************************************
- Unable to join channel. Member data for presence channel missing 
******************************************
- OWCJjy4o64iDbqMOAAAA joined channel: presence-presence-channel.1
```

Laravel channels.php:

```
Broadcast::channel('private-channel.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('presence-channel.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return ['id'=>$id,'user'=>$user->name];
});
```

Laravel BroadcastServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

Laravel .env config

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT = predis
REDIS_PREFIX=
```

Clientcode:

```
echo!.join('presence-channel.1').here((users) {
      logger.e(jsonEncode(users));
    }).joining((user) {
      logger.e(jsonEncode(user));
    }).leaving((user) {
      logger.e(jsonEncode(user));
    }).listen('presence-channel PresenceEvent: ', (e) {
      logger.e(e);
    });
```

I have tried most solutions with no luck, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `BROADCAST_DRIVER` value to `redis`
and `REDIS_CLIENT` to `predis` in your .env
After, do `composer required predis/predis` if not present

Replace `Broadcast::routes(['auth:sanctum']);` in BroadcastServiceProvider class with `Broadcast::routes();`

Comment: It is made already. updated the question.

Comment: All of that are already made. see the question updated.

Comment: try to just return $user instead of the array in channel.php

Comment: tried that with no luck

Comment: `Broadcast::routes();` did nothing